# Targeting specific Page Template for sidebar page

Tags: custom-post-types, sidebar

Currently, there is a sidebar dedicated to all posts, and one for all pages. What I would like to do is target specific page templates to display sidebars for each template.

```
if(is_front_page())
            {
              if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Blog Sidebar") ) :
              endif;

            }
            else if(get_post_type($post) == "post" || is_search()  )
            {
              if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Blog Sidebar") ) :
              endif;

            }
            else if((get_post_type($post) != "post" && get_post_type($post) != "page") || get_post_type() == "")
            {
              if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Portfolio Sidebar") ) :
              endif;

            }
            else if(get_post_type($post) == "page" || is_author() || is_404() )
            {
              if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Page Sidebar") ) :
              endif;

            }
```

So instead of posting "Page Sidebar" for all of the pages. I would like to target, for example, the products.php template so that I can put a specific sidebar for those pages.

I have added into functions, additional dynamic_sidebars but I need to find a way to target them on this sidebar.php.

IF you need more info please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress is very accommodating when it comes to conditionals:

```
if (is_page_template('products.php')) {
...
```